# showing to users that the site is in beta and things might break

Tags: website-design, beta

We are planning to launch a new site to the public for testing and initial feedback. We're wondering about how to let users know that things might break. Currently, we're thinking of adding a banner at the bottom of the homepage. [image: banner]

Any suggestions on how to do it better?

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would put this information at the top of the application view/window if it is really important for the users to understand this. Often we also see the text 'beta' put right next to the home or logo just so that it appears at the prominent part of the site.

If you have reasons that you want to put it at the bottom, then it is important that if something does break that you also provide some error handling mechanism to let the users know that this is a beta site and that they can help improve it by reporting the bugs or issues they find.